# Reading pending records of SqlTransaction in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an `InsertUpdate` stored procedure which is being executed in C# via `SqlTransaction`.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=shsqldev;Initial Catalog=CATALOG;User ID=ID;Password=PASS;"))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction("testTransaction");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(tSql, connection)
    {
        Transaction = sqlTransaction,
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };

    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(storedProcedureParameters.Select(p => new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = p.ParameterName,
        Value = p.ParameterValue
    }).ToArray());

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sqlTransaction.Commit();

    connection.Close();
}
```

What I want to do is read from the pending records prior to

```
SqlTransaction.Commit()
```

I want to read the actual records, not just know the number of rows.

Is this sort of thing possible ?

Comment: Does your stored proc return those pending records?

Comment: When `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` returns, the rows exist in the database and can be read on that very same connection. You do need a way to find the rows; there is no "where not yet committed" filtering in SQL. Only the stored procedure knows what rows were inserted/updated.

Comment: @mjwills No, which is the reason this is such a headache. 

1. There are far too many stored procedures to have to add this to. Literally almost 2k so this is unfortunately not an option for me. :\

2. These sp's are maintainted by a business so even if I could update them all, they would not allow it since it goes into production.

Comment: @mjwills Oh wow nice article. Never heard of the XY problem. What I want to do is basically track alterations in the database after a stored procedure has been ran. Surely there has to be a simpler solution than creating a service to synchronize with the database. At least that is what I was hoping for. 

So in short, I want to sync with database but only after a stored proc is ran without having to read the entire database.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's what I was afraid of. No real way to differentiating uncommitted and committed transactions. :\

Comment: @mjwills I don't thnk they would allow adding triggers to all of the stored procedures :\ I can pretty much get away with any C# workarounds but messing with the database directly I think would be frowned upon.

Comment: Triggers are added to tables, not stored procedures. The short answer is - this is a very hard problem to solve if the constraint is you can't touch the DB.

Comment: @mjwills Which only makes my case even worse since there are tenfold tables in comparison to stored procedures. They definitely would not allow me to edit all of the tables -- even just to add triggers. It sounds like a difficult if even possible thing I am trying to do :\